# What is meant by "fuel flow: on " in checklists?

Tags: engine-starting

What is mean by "fuel flow: on " in checklists? For example:

http://www.projectlear45.nl/docs/Checklist_LEAR45.pdf

Comment: I looked at the checklist.  If I didn't know better I would assume  it meant "fuel flow: cutoff" in the pre-start checklist means no fuel to the engine; engine better be off.  In the startup checklist "fuel flow: on" would mean give the engine some fuel so you can start the engine.   How long you been flying Lear may I ask?

Comment: @user6035379 considering that checklist is a flightsim one (unless `ctrl+shift+f4` is a thing in learjets) I suspect the answer to your question is "oh, donkey's years - in flight sim" :)

Comment: @user6035379 Thank you for the answer. I myself have not been flying learjet except of simulators.

Comment: @Jamiec : get a badge for knowing what checklist I looked at and yeah ... donkey..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the real aircraft that checklist item would mean bringing the thrust lever of the engine to be started up out of `cutoff` and to the `idle` position. This would be accomplished by physically moving the thrust lever forward slightly out of the `cutoff` detent.

However, in the computer flight sim for which the linked checklist provides guidance, the `cutoff` position of the thrust levers is not simulated. Instead, thrust lever positions below idle command reverse thrust. For this reason, the checklist calls for using the computer keystroke `ctrl-shift-F4` to command fuel flow on. This keystroke combination commands `mixture full rich` in simulated piston aircraft.

In the real Lear 45, fuel flow and scheduling during start is controlled by the Digital Electronic Engine Control (DEEC). For this reason, the start checklist calls for setting the appropriate thrust lever to idle prior to commanding engine spool up in preparation for the DEEC to automatically start actual fuel flow once the appropriate compressor speed is achieved.

It is worth noting that after initially setting the thrust lever to `idle`—or hitting `ctrl-shift-F4` on your computer—the fuel flow indication should read zero. The check for appropriate positive fuel flow comes later in the start sequence.

Compared to setting the thrust lever to `idle` in the Lear 45, the analogous control command for starting most piston engines would be mixture to `full rich` and for most turboprop aircraft would be fuel condition lever to `low idle` or similar.